# Articles in menu items

Tags: articles

I found articles are omitted in menu items(Open File, Create Folder). Is there a rule that I should follow?
I'm wondering do I need to add articles to these items?

> Create `a` Box
>   Delete `the` Selected Objects
>   Close `the` Window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see it as a form of [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) (Wikipedia). Headlinese is a rough guideline of abbreviated language used in newspaper headlines to save space. However, the usage extends beyond headlines. I would say it applies here too, since menu items use limited space. Specifically,

> - Forms of the verb "to be" and articles (a, an, the) are usually omitted.
> - Most verbs are in the simple present tense, e.g. "Governor signs bill", while the future is expressed by an infinitive, with to followed by a verb, as in "Governor to sign bill".

In this style, your examples with the articles omitted sound fine to me as menu items.